# which layer of a web app i should depict in uml class diagram only model or model + controller both

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, web, uml

I am new to UML. Now in a web project i want to apply UML class diagram then should i include controller layer also in the UML class diagram or only model layer classes should be there . I am using spring web MVC framework, even if i include controller layer also in the uml class diagram then how to represent spring library specific classes(i. e the hierarchy of spring specific controller classes).

one more thing is when i will draw UML class diagram it will be only one for whole model layer or for every requirement or use case i draw one because if i draw single UML class diagram it's becoming messy as i have too many classes in model layer.

also how many diagram should be fine. Initially i find 1. use case diagram 2. activity / sequence diagram 3. UML class diagram this three are good to go.

please advice.

Comment: You should do whatever you think is the best way to document what you want to document. UML is just a tool at your disposal.

Comment: Try to click through the "best practices" image map at http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/bestPractices.htm it should give you some good answers for the "how many" or "which ones". Also 1st studying some examples from other existing projects can be a good guide. I don't know where exactly such a comprehensive examples could be found (Googled) but you can look at some small inspiration at http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when you design an app, you first make a **platform-independent information design model** in the form of a UML class diagram, which is not tailored towards any framework such as Spring. From this design model, you derive a (platform-specific) **Java/Spring data model** that only include the model layer classes.

There is normally no need to include the Spring controller classes in your UML application model, since their structure can be derived from the model-layer classes.

Comment: can i depict my own controller classes in UML class diagram which i will extend from frameworks controller classes just to show the association between controller and model classes.please advice.

Comment: Yes, sure, you can add the corresponding controller classes to your model classes just to document the software architecture of your app. But for designing your app the controller classes are useless.